# mathjax "exclude" from initial render

Tags: javascript, mathjax

With Mathjax 3.2.1 we got the "lazyAlwaysTypeset" option to specify containers that should still be rendered upon page load even if lazy rendering is enabled.

We would actually like to do the opposite: We have quite some "details" elements on the page that will probably never be opened by the user containing math.

Is there a way to specify a "render everything EXCEPT this" upon page load?

The "not" specifier for a css selector for "lazyAlwaysTypeset" is useless in this case because we will most definetly select a container of the details element we do not want to render, thus still triggering a render upon these elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the standard [options](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/options/document.html#document-options-1) to control which sections of your document are processed by MathJax; no need for a new one.  For example, if you add `tex2jax_ignore` as a class on a paragraph, the math in that paragraph will not be processed by MathJax, regardless of whether the lazy typesetting extension is used or not.  So you can mark any sections you don't want processed in that way.

Comment: Issue is that these ignored sections can also not be rendered after the initial render is done and you call something like `MathJax.typeset([element])`. A re-setting of the config and reinitialisation of MathJax is needed in order to allow that. It is actually not that much of a hassle, but it improves our load times by ~4 - 6 seconds.

Comment: The other option is to remove the `tex2jax_ignore` class from the elements you want to process before making the `MathJax.typeset()` call, rather than re-initializing MathJax (which will likely cause it to lose track of the math it has already processed, or confuse the lazy typesetting extension).